# Proper usage of the expression “words fail me"

Tags: expressions, spoken-english

I am trying to use the expression “words fail me” and I want to know if these sentences are formed correctly:

> 1. Look at this mess, words fail me.
> 2. This comment is so ridiculous that words fail me.

Is there any other proper expressions with similar nuance above sentences, please let me know.

Comment: You are using the phrase properly. Note that the phrase is not always critical or sarcastic.  *Words fail me to say how much he meant to this nation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Words fail (someone)** is an idiomatic expression of *inability to describe* something *with words*, (usually) being overwhelmed with some emotion (shock, surprise, fear). There's also another expression with a similar sense: (being) **lost for words**.

Here are examples from three different books:

> My heart is so full, yet my **words fail me**.
>
> Sometimes, however, **words fail us** as speakers and we find a
>   picture truly is worth a thousand words.
>
> I now realize most people scatter in times of true suffering,
>   overwhelmed and awkward when **words fail them** as they attempt to
>   console.

There's also a less idiomatic version: **words fail** (e. g. **to describe something**).